# Prove that it is a basis for a Lie algebra

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that B = {∂x, ∂y, x∂y + ∂z} is a base of the Lie algebra h of H (h is known as the Heisenberg algebra)
In the context of the 3 × 3 matrices, I have problems to proceed since I do not have much practice and in this example I am totally lost, do you know any bibliography specifically for this topic?

Answer (score 3):

A basis for the [Heisenberg Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Lie_algebra_2) is made up of 3 generators, say $\{X,Y,Z\}$, satisfying
$$
[X,Y]=Z, [X,Z]=[Y,Z]=0.
$$ 
Call $X=\partial/\partial x$, $Y=x\partial/\partial y+\partial/\partial z$ and
$Z=\partial/\partial y$ and compute the commutators.

Answer (score 1):

The Heisenberg group is the set of matrices of the form

$$H=\begin{bmatrix}1 &a &b\\0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \text{ where }a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$$

To determine its Lie algebra, you should take a smooth path $H(t)$ in the Lie group that starts at the identity element, i.e. $H(0)=I$. Such a path is very easy to find. Just consider the path $H(t)$ parametrized by $t$ given by

$$H(t)=\begin{bmatrix}1 &\psi(t) &\varphi(t)\\0 & 1 & \rho(t) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\psi,\varphi,\rho: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are real-valued single variable functions of $t$ such that $\psi(0)=\varphi(0)=\rho(0)=0$.

Differentiating $H(t)$ with respect to $t$ at $0$ tells us that the Lie algebra of the Heisenberg group consists of matrices of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & \psi'(0)&\varphi'(0)\\0 & 0 & \rho'(0) \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}0 & \alpha&\beta\\0 & 0 & \gamma \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ where }\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$$

A Lie algebra is first of all a vector space. So, you must be able to see the basis now. Let's call them $\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta},\bar{\gamma}$. But a Lie algebra is also an algebra, so you must determine the relations between the generators. You can see that you have the following relations with respect to the Lie bracket:

$$[\bar{\alpha},\bar{\gamma}]=\bar{\beta}$$
$$[\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta}]=[\bar{\beta},\bar{\gamma}]=0$$

This shows you how the Lie algebra of the Heisenberg group is derived.

To show what you have been given is isomorphic to this as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, it suffices to determine a correspondence between your set and the generators of the Lie algebra of the Heiseinberg group. As suggested by jobe, here's a correspondence: $$\bar{\alpha} \leftrightarrow \partial_x, \hspace{15px} \bar{\beta} \leftrightarrow \partial_y, \hspace{15px} \bar{\gamma} \leftrightarrow x\partial_y+\partial_z$$

For example, you can check that $[\partial_x, x \partial_y + \partial_z]=\color{purple}{1}\partial_y + \color{green}{x \partial_x \partial_y} + \color{blue}{\partial_x \partial_z} - (\color{green}{x\partial_y \partial_x} + \color{blue}{\partial_z \partial_x}) = \partial_y$ because the order of partial differential operators can be switched.
You can similarly see that other relations are zero.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks for taking the time to edit my post. I had forgotten to write the variables as subscripts. Nice job.

Comment: You're welcome. I forget too sometimes. Nice answer, btw.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thank you. Unfortunately, I had to edit my answer again because there was a typo. I had said "differentiating with respect to 0" while what I meant is differentiating with respect to $t$ at $0$.